# Is nullptr falsy?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion, nullptr

When used as a boolean expression or transformed into a boolean either explicitly or implicitly, is `nullptr` consistently false? Is this implementation defined or specified in the standard?

I wrote some code to test, but am not certain if it tests this property fully. I couldn't find an existing SO answer that talked specifically about this. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) doesn't mention this from what I see.

```
if (nullptr) {
    ;
} else {
    std::cout << "Evaluates to false implicitly\n";
}

if (!nullptr) {
    std::cout << "Evaluates to false if operated on\n";
}

if (!(bool)(nullptr)) {
    std::cout << "Evaluates to false if explicitly cast to bool\n";
}
```

Expected and actual:

```
Evaluates to false implicitly
Evaluates to false if operated on
Evaluates to false if explicitly cast to bool
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/177007/8038186

Comment: Huh, true, cppreference doesn't say it. At least not directly.

Comment: "is nullptr consistently false?" - Yes.

Comment: found it here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion and scroll down to "§Boolean conversions". I agree it should be mentioned on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr

Comment: @bolov: So just suggest the change there, no need to discuss it here...

Comment: @WalterNissen "Falsy" (aka "falsey") is not a misspelling. It means something like "false when (implicitly?) converted to bool".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I'm a native English speaker, "falsy" is not a common (or even uncommon) word. It's slang in a limited community. Better to be explicit and use the fully expanded phrase as you have provided. My edit was unambiguous, we should strive for that.

Comment: @WalterNissen It seems to be primarily a [JS term](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), but I've seen it applied to other languages (like here). "Is nullptr false" is a bit ambiguous, because `nullptr` is not a `bool` to begin with. "Is nullptr false when converted to bool" is ok.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to the C++ 17 Standard (5.13.7 Pointer literals)

> 1 The pointer literal is the keyword nullptr. It is a prvalue of type
>   std::nullptr_t. [ Note: **std::nullptr_t is a distinct type that is
>   neither a pointer type nor a pointer-to-member type; rather, a prvalue
>   of this type is a null pointer constant** and can be converted to a
>   null pointer value or null member pointer value. See 7.11 and 7.12. —
>   end note ]

And (7 Standard conversions)

> 4 Certain language constructs require that an expression be converted
>   to a Boolean value. **An expression e appearing in such a context is
>   said to be contextually converted to bool and is well-formed if and
>   only if the declaration bool t(e); is well-formed**, for some invented
>   temporary variable t (11.6).

And at last (7.14 Boolean conversions)

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or
>   pointer-to-member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A
>   zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is
>   converted to false; any other value is converted to true. **For
>   direct-initialization (11.6), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.**

That is you may write for example

```
bool b( nullptr );
```

but you may not write (though some compilers have a bug relative to this)

```
bool b = nullptr;
```

So `nullptr` can be contextually converted to an object of the type bool for example in selection statements like the if-statement.

Let's consider for example the unary operator `!` as in an if statement

```
if ( !nullptr ) { /*...*/ }
```

According to the description of the operator (8.5.2.1 Unary operators)

> 9 **The operand of the logical negation operator ! is contextually
>   converted to bool** (Clause 7); its value is true if the converted
>   operand is false and false otherwise. The type of the result is bool

So `nullptr` in this expression is not converted to a pointer. It is directly contextually converted to bool.

Answer (score 5):

The result of your code is guaranteed, [[dcl.init]/17.8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#17.8)

> Otherwise, if the initialization is direct-initialization, the source type is `std​::​nullptr_­t`, and the destination type is `bool`, the initial value of the object being initialized is `false`.

That means, for direct-initialization, a `bool` object may be initialized from `nullptr`, with the result value `false`. Then for `(bool)(nullptr)`, `nullptr` is converted to `bool` with value `false`.

When using `nullptr` as condition of `if` or the operand of `operator!`, it's considered as [contextual conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions),

> the implicit conversion is performed if the declaration `bool t(e);` is well-formed

That means, both `if (nullptr)` and `!nullptr`, `nullptr` will be converted to `bool` with value `false`.

Comment: It is an incorrect answer. std::nullptr_t
is a distinct type that is neither a pointer type nor a pointer-to-member type. nullptr t is a null pointer constant and can be contextually converted to bool.

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes, but you should avoid using this fact.

Comparing pointers to `false`, or to `0`, is a common trope in C/C++ coding. I suggest that you *avoid using it*. If you want to check for nullness, use:

```
if (x == nullptr) { /* ... */}
```

rather than

```
if (!x) { /* ... */}
```

or

```
if (not x) { /* ... */}
```

The second variant adds another bit of confusion for the reader: What is `x`? Is it a boolean? A plain value (e.g. an integer)? A pointer? An optional? Even if `x` has a meaningful name, it won't help you much: `if (!network_connection)` ... it could still be a complex structure convertible to an integer or a boolean, it might be a boolean indicator of whether there's a connection, it could a pointer, a value or an optional. Or something else.

Also, remembering that `nullptr` evaluates to false is another bit of information you need to store in the back of your brain to properly decode the code you're reading. We may be used to it from the olden days or from reading other people's code - but if we weren't, it would not have been obvious that `nullptr` behaves like that. In a sense, it's not dissimilar for other obscure guarantees, like how [the value at index 0 of an empty `std::string` is guaranteed to be `\0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33088349/1593077). Just don't make your code rely on this stuff unless you absolutely have to.

---

PS :  There is actually a lot less use for null pointers these days. You can [force pointers to never be null](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ri-nullptr) if they don't need to; you can use references instead of pointers; and you can use `std::optional<T>` to return either a `T` or "no T". Perhaps you could just avoid mentioning `nullptr` altogether.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your advice. C is about *how* and C++ is about *what*. That's why you have `auto`: it means that you don't need to know the type. In the same line, `if (!network_connection)` is clear, and you shouldn't care whether `network_connection` is a class convertible to `bool` or a pointer. The code in C++ should express *intent* from the programmer.

Comment: @Mirko: Even if you're interested in "what", then "not x" is still often kind of confusing.